# Azure health data service - DICOM service

Tags: azure

I’m exploring DICOM service in Azure health data service. Following the Microsoft tutorial for DICOM service, I have also created a health service and deployed it in Azure. I’m facing two challenges while getting an access token in Azure PowerShell as mentioned in shorturl.at/dmnQZ:

1. I’m unable to obtain a token by executing this command "$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl 'https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com').Token" . It returns 400 bad request with the error "Get-AzAccessToken: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed."

2. Where can I get the version of the REST API "Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Headers $headers -Uri 'https://.dicom.azurehealthcareapis.com/**v**/changefeed'"?

As Azurehealthdataservice is very new, I’m unable to get the needed.

Answer (score 1):

> I’m unable to obtain a token by executing this command "$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl 'https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com').Token" . It returns 400 bad request with the error "Get-AzAccessToken: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.

- According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/configure-azure-rbac#assign-roles-for-the-dicom-service), make sure to assign a specific role and [enable authentication with the token](https://github.com/microsoft/dicom-server/blob/main/docs/how-to-guides/enable-authentication-with-tokens.md).

  DICOM Data Owner: Full access to DICOM data.

  DICOM Data Reader: Read and search DICOM data.

> Where can I get the version of the REST API "Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Headers $headers -Uri 'https://.dicom.azurehealthcareapis.com/v/changefeed'"?

- According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/dicom/api-versioning-dicom-service), currently `v1` is supported version.
- According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/healthcareapis/dicom-services/get?tabs=HTTP), you can get the properties of the specified DICOM Service:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.HealthcareApis/workspaces/{workspaceName}/dicomservices/{dicomServiceName}?api-version=2021-11-01
```